# Equivalent definition of bounded set in topological vector space.

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to know relation between two defination of bounded set in topological vector space : i am using defination that set A is said to be bdd in topological vector space X if it is contain in some nbhd of zero vector.nkw my question is
(1) is my definition is only true for topological vector space whose topology is metrizable(in metrizable tvs by nbhd i mean what we find by some positive radius)?
(2) if Answer of question 1 is "yes" then how it is equivalent to the definition : set A is said to be bounded if For every neighborhood V of the origin there exists a scalar s such that set A is contained in sV.
(3) in metrizable topological vector space  can we say set is bdd if it contain in some nbhd of any point rather than zero vector?

If anyone have relation between other equivalent definition then plz provide with proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ is any topological vector space then $X$ is  itself a neighborhood of $0$. According to your definition $X$ (and hence also every subset) is bounded. Whether $X$ is metrizable or nor this definition does not agree with  the usual definition.

If $X$ is a normed linear space then $A$ is bounded (according to the standard definition) if and only if $A$ is contained in  some open ball around $0$: Suppose $A$ is bounded. Then $V\equiv\{x: \|x\| <1\}$ is a neighborhood of $0$ so there exists $s>0$ such that $A\subseteq sV$. But then $A \subseteq B(0,s)$ (the open ball of radius $s$ around $0$).
Conversely, let $A \subseteq B(0,s)$. Let $V$ be any neighborhood of $0$. Then $B(0,r) \subseteq V$ for some $r>0$ (by definition of neighborhood in a metric space). But then $A \subseteq \frac s rV$.

Comment: Sorry my fault In metrizable tvs i said nbhd means what we find by choosing some positive real radius.then definition 1 is correct for metrizable topological vector space?

Comment: What the B and X are?

Comment: So what ?you are specifying topology  and it is possible that for tvs all set r bdd

Comment: Can u provide definition of bdd set in metrizable tvs?i mean what  new equivalent definition arise due to metrizability?

Comment: Its tough  to prove how they are equal. Can u plz do it?that in normed linear space set A is contained in some nbhd of 0 with radius r iff For every neighborhood V of the 0 there exists a scalar s such that set A is contained in sV.

Comment: ohh now i got  what u are trying to tell by example on R... Thanks thats help me a lot .

Comment: If tvs is metrizable with induced metric by norm then my definition agree. And it is not necessarily true for arbitrary metrizable tvs.  Right? Plz confirm...@geetha290krm

Comment: Yes, that is right.  @MEETPATEL